# React.js SPA security issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I would to discuss on how to secure an app that is SPA in React with server-side rendering in Node.js, but accessing our API on a different server so it wouldn't be vulnerable to various cross-site attacks and other security issues.

We have JWT token issued on the API server, but that means storing the token in cookie to be able to ship it to the API server after page reload, which is not the best idea I think. Do you have some better solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is to make one gateway which does all the validation of token and authentication. For that what you will need.

1) redis to store your token and session data.

2) store your token in redis don't ever give it to the browser.

3) for accessing token from redis you should generate some special 
   saltedhash which you can store to client cookie.(make cookie secure and 
   HTTP only for cross-domain attack)

4) use this cookie for retrieving token and validate on the gateway before request goes to your api server.

[image]